# Simple Twilio test in AWS Lambda failure

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to set up the example AWS Lambda to respond to a text message. I am using Python 3.8 and have the following very simple code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + str(event))
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Response><Message>Hello world 4! -Lambda</Message></Response>"
```

This appears to return exactly the XML format specified in the API document:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Response><Message>Hello world 4! -Lambda</Message></Response>"
```

This gives me a 12200 "Content is not allowed in prolog." Error. I cannot see what the problem is with this XML string. It looks to be formatted exactly as the API Doc says. Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the valid TwiML (not sure why you have the output in quotes and the escaped quotes?).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>Hello world 4! -Lambda</Message>
</Response>
```

Comment: This is the precise code that Twilio indicates on the example page for setting up an AWS Lambda. The escaped " is how Twilio shows the output in the debugger. The escapes are not actually in the transmitted string.